# PHP month payment filter

Tags: php, html

ok still on the php learning curve. ive been building a simple books system for myself as a way to push my basic skills.

i have a list that is pulled from a database of information i have inputted. i was woundering if there was a way to filter it to a month if needed to look up a months information. i was thinking of 2 date boxes that i pick and it displays all the information between the dates inputed? my code can be found below:

```
<style>

</style>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    </head>
<?php
include 'db-connect.php'; 

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM payments");

echo "<table border='0' align='center' text-align='left'>
<tr>
<th>Title:</th>
<th>Date:</th>
<th>Incoming:</th>
<th>Outgoing:</th>
<th>Notes:</th>
</tr>";

$totalIncoming = 0;
    $totalOutgoing = 0;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {
      $totalIncoming += $row['incoming'];
      $totalOutgoing += $row['outgoing'];
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['title'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td> £" . $row['incoming'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td> £" .  $row['outgoing'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['notes'] . "</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
      }
    echo "</table>";
$profit = $totalIncoming - $totalOutgoing;
    echo "<div class='payment-total'><h1>Profit : £" . "$profit</h1></div>";


mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM payments WHERE \`date\` BETWEEN '2013-11-01' AND '2013-11-30'`? MySQL `BETWEEN ... AND ...` - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between

Comment: i was thinking more in terms of not having to go though the code to do it

Comment: @user2827404 How would you be able to filter like that without coding? You would need code to generate the date input fields. You would need code to capture the dates from the input fields. You would need code to change your SQL to filter on the input dates. There is no magic "filter my database for me" button you can add.

Comment: not to go through what code? you have to change some code to alter your results.

Comment: i mean like having a text box on the site i can input the data in and it works to that. instead of having to go into the code and do it if you get what i mean

Comment: even with a text box you still need to modify your code to change your data results. If you don't want to change the mysql/php code, you could use a javascript script to filter. DataTables - http://datatables.net/ or JTable - http://www.jtable.org/

Comment: i get that i have to edit the code initially, i just dont want to do it every time i want to change the month, if you get what i mean. how can i do it so i set up 2 boxes and the dates inserted into the 2 boxes then the dates inbetween is loaded. does that make more sense?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM Payments
WHERE your_date BETWEEN to_date ('2003/01/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd') AND to_date ('2003/12/31', 'yyyy/mm/dd');
```

Comment: i was thinking more in terms of not having to go though the code to do it